# PHP function utf8_decode is not available. Maybe your hosting provider disabled it for some reason?

Tags: php, dokuwiki

Trying to install dokuwiki on ubuntu. I have php 7.2 installed. When I go to site I can see the page

> This topic does not exist yet

When I go to installer I get the error:

> PHP function utf8_decode is not available. Maybe your hosting provider disabled it for some reason?

I tried;

- Installing php-xml
- Installing php-mbstring
- Having seperate php.ini file for dokuwiki and enabling this extensions.

But still can not get it to work.